# Executing the Visual Studio created *.exe does not open a window and the process can not be terminated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I created a small C# Project in Visual Studio 2015 which does some simple Text manipulation. Starting the application from inside Visual Studio works fine. If I start one of the created exe files (debug/release), a process starts, but the main window never opens. I am not able to stop the process via Taskmanager or cmd.
I've attempted:

- using different target frameworks 3.5/4
- eliminating references
- starting a new project and adding the original source files and form
- creating a setup.exe -> same behaviour, also on different computer
- reinstalling Visual Studio
- debugging the exe (Note: I don't have any experience debugging Windows applications)
  All my attempts crashed the debugger
- building an older project: still works fine

At this point, I really have no idea what the problem is. I've uploaded the project to GitHub: https://github.com/webbertee/FrequencyDataTool

Comment: Try disabling your anti-virus, especially if you are running AVG.

Comment: I built your project. It ran just fine for me, both in Visual Studio, and in Release mode outside of Visual studio. So I officially cannot replicate this problem.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Your coding style does not in any way follow the C# coding conventions. Your functions start with lower case letters and you have a few constants that are in all uppercase, when they should be defined as regular whole words with a single upper case at the beginning.

Comment: are you using that horrid Avast?

Comment: The best anti virus in the world is free, it's called "Common Sense".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, avast does this. Disabling avast fixed the problem. Thank you for your help =)