# windows form dont start on other machines and process can't be closed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I've got a problem with my windows form application.
I wrote a simple program that can create .VTF / .VMT files out of .TGA files and can generate a .QC file and also compile this all with a .SMD file into a prop for the sourceSDK (Hammer Editor). So i can use this to bypass the incredible annoying task with compiling custom models for a map in Counter Strike.

Previously i could compile my form (same with other applications) and send it to someone so he can use it. This time it compiles normal and works fine on my system, but after i sent it to my friend it didn't start. He clicked at the .exe and his explorer.exe froze. After some time his explorer came back but he couldn't move or delete the file.
He also tried to restart his system, but afterward it still refuses to delete the file and then bluescreen. (The bluescreen said something about an Errorcode = 0xc000021a)

An other friend tried to start the .exe too, but he got the same problem with the explorer ...

I use Visual Studio 2015 to write and compile my code. My target Framework is .Net 4.5.2. 
Does someone know how to solve this problem?

What further information do you need?

Thank you for your help
Greetings 
Marv

EDIT #1: I think the bluescreen isn't that important for that problem.
We tried it again with serveral .NET Versions and it won't work at all.
The funny thing is that i sent him the whole Visual Studio project and told him to compile it on his system. The debug version in Visual Studio works fine but if he wants to start the release.exe in the subfolder /bin/release/ the same problem occurs..

Comment: The type of people who open raw executables from other people are in the same group as those who have viruses on their machine.  An error code of `0xc000021a` means [`STATUS_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560177(v=vs.85).aspx).  Can you perform a virus scan on both machines to rule out the possibility of a virus?

Comment: Try adding some logging in your code to work out where the issue is occurring.  Stick lots of calls to write to the log in your code stating where execution has got to, and then once you've worked out exactly where the issue is you should be able to produce a small code sample to reproduce the issue.  Once you have that you're a lot more likely to get an answer.  Here's some logging info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409264/winforms-logging-framework.  HTH

Comment: does it work on your machine in release mode? Did you choose the same cpu architecture for both debug and release?

Comment: @lobiZoli Yes, it works fine in all versions on my machine. The cpu architecture is AnyCPU for both versions but we tried it with the other one too.

Comment: If the executable gets locked on a machine even after restart it is most likely in quarantine by antivirus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution to this problem with some help from here:
[C# exe not starting on Win7 build computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724858/c-sharp-exe-not-starting-on-win7-build-computer?rq=1)

and here: 
[Executing the Visual Studio created *.exe does not open a window and the process can not be terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125371/executing-the-visual-studio-created-exe-does-not-open-a-window-and-the-process?rq=1)

**He only has to turn off his avast antivirus...**

EDIT #1: I found out that disabling the "*Deepscreen*" feature in Avast is enough to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help